# Where are dll libraries stored in VS .Net?

Tags: c#, dll, shared-libraries

I wonder where dll files are stored in Visual Studio and whether its the best way to keep them there or consolidate elsewhere for the following cases:

1) My solution includes a c# library project which other projects in the same solution reference to. My understanding is that the library project stores the dll in its own directory /bin folder. So do I need to establish the reference to that library by pointing to the dll in that external folder? Problem is that this dll should later be shipped with the projects referencing to the dll file. Will the projects who reference to the dll file create a copy of the dll in their own project /bin folders or how does it work?

2) where should I copy external libraries to that are referenced by projects I like to ship in compiled fashion? Should a dll be copies and referenced to into each project's bin folder that utilizes such external library?

I am a bit confused by how going practice is and could not find straightforward answers in other posts here.

Thanks

Comment: My understanding is.. If you will add the Project reference then the Library project DLL will be copied to your Project's BIN folder. so, later on you can safely move your project to anywhere your library projects will be there in BIN folder

Comment: I think those DLL's will be looked up in process's current directory and then by %PATH%

Comment: @ Hitesh and Roman, this confuses me quite a bit because if that was the case, how does it work when I re-build the dll library that the projects referencing this dll will always reference the most up-to-date library code? So, the link to the library folder must still be in existence under the hood, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can set two solutions one for your dll referenced and another for your project that reference them after

1. create a dependencies folder where you will set all binaries that are dll you need
2. set path to this dependencies folder on all your projects that will create   dll you want to reference
3. set build order on your solution to first build your dll and after build your project that reference your dll

when you deploy it, make sure that you create dependencies folder

For your information, your application first see on GAC folder (windows\assembly), after see on your current path, and after use PATH environment variable.

Comment: Ah, so if I understand you correctly, is it that the copy of the dll in the project which references the dll is up-to-date because of the compile/build order? Also, what does "when you deploy it, make sure that you create dependencie folder" mean? Does this have to be done manually? I thought the release built had all referenced dlls in its own /bin folder and thus would ship it with the project itself.

Comment: if you reference this library on bin\debug or bin\release (default output binaries folder) or on your, and if your solution contain the project of dll, when you make a build, this will update your reference. So, according to build order, if your dll project is built after your project that reference it because of clean your dll will be first deleted  and your project won't find it.

Comment: Ha, I think this was exactly my problem. Thanks a lot, I think the build order was messed up.

Comment: Happy to help you my friend ;-)